# Docker doesn't start a new Ubuntu-based container after its downloading

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Trying to start a new container using `docker run` I've seen that the container is created but not runs.

I've tried to do this:

`docker run -d --name server -p 5000:80 ubuntu:20.10`

Expected:

A container with ubuntu running on my machine

Actual results:

The container is created but not running. I've checked it with the command:
`docker ps` and then `docker ps -a`
The output is:

[image]

What's wrong with the instruction?

Thanks

Comment: [Don't post screen shots of code or status messages.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WumnW.png)

Comment: A Docker container typically runs a single process.  What's the process or command that you want the container to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each container must have a command to run. By default, these OS containers  doesn't run anything at all. As you can see in [Dockerfile for Ubuntu](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/74249faf47098bef2cedad89696bfd1ed521e019/groovy/Dockerfile) sample , it just runs `/bin/bash` command, which doesn't do anything and exits right after starting.
If you want to keep it running, you can run a "non-ending" command. For example:

```
docker run -d ubuntu:20.10 tail -f /dev/null
```

This command never ends، so that you can come back later and use this container whenever you want.

**P.S.** Passing `-d` implies that the container should be run in the background.

Comment: Hagh gofti dash Ali :)))

Answer (score 0):

`docker run` just let run `CMD` in Dockerfile, even if added option `-d`. [ubuntu:20.10](https://hub.docker.com/layers/ubuntu/library/ubuntu/20.10/images/sha256-c41e8d2a4ca9cddb4398bf08c99548b9c20d238f575870ae4d3216bc55ef3ca7?context=explore) exec `/bin/bash` at last. `bash` normally awaits input from user, but docker doesn't have terminal and input, so `bash` finished soon. Though, you add options `-it`, docker has input and virtual terminal so `bash` continues to alive. Try it!